# Detect changes to a form when the row are added dynamically

Tags: jquery, forms

How can I detect changes to a form when the row are added dynamically using the clone() function in jQuery.

This is what I tried:

```
$('table input').change(function() {
    // Execute the function
});
```

This function is working when the row is here from the beginning but not when the row is cloned.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by using this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'table input', function() {
    // Execute the function
});
```